# IndexError: too many indices for array, trainingframes[h, :, :, :]

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to run a microexpression recognition code, here is the link : https://github.com/bogireddytejareddy/micro-expression-recognition

I am getting a specific error, here's the code in which error is thrown:

```
training_list = [a.reshape(-1, 2) for a in training_list]
training_list = numpy.asarray(training_list)
trainingsamples = len(training_list)
traininglabels = numpy.zeros((trainingsamples, ), dtype = int)

traininglabels[0:66] = 0
traininglabels[66:113] = 1
traininglabels[113:156] = 2

traininglabels = np_utils.to_categorical(traininglabels, 3)

training_data = [training_list, traininglabels]
(trainingframes, traininglabels) = (training_data[0], training_data[1])
training_set = numpy.zeros((trainingsamples, 1, image_rows, image_columns, image_depth))

for h in range(trainingsamples):
    training_set[h][0][:][:][:] = trainingframes[h, :, :, :]

training_set = training_set.astype('float32')
training_set -= numpy.mean(training_set)
training_set /= numpy.max(training_set)
```

The error window is:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Rajat_Sharma/PycharmProjects/untitled1/micro-expression-recognition-master/SMIC/MicroExpSTCNN.py", line 93, in <module>
    training_set[h][0][:][:][:] = trainingframes[h, :, :, :]
IndexError: too many indices for array

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help. Forgive me for erring something obvious, but I am beginner.

Edit: the shape of training_set is printed as (7, 1, 64, 64, 18) and the shape of trainingframes is printed as (7,) Now please tell me what to change in the code ? Many thanx.

Comment: I think a lot of context is missing here to give a precise answer. Is this code taken from a specific file from the linked repo? What I can say for sure is that the indexing of `training_set[h][0][:][:][:] = trainingframes[h, :, :, :]` should look more like `training_set[n, 0] = trainingframes[h]` - pointing to another thing; it seems like `trainingframes.shape` should be `(64, 64, 18)`, not `(7,)`.

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes, the code is taken from a linked repo. I have provided the link in the question. I am just running the code as it is after downloading necessary packages and libraries.

Comment: I mean which file from the repo, like [this](https://github.com/bogireddytejareddy/micro-expression-recognition/blob/master/CASME-SQUARE/Intermediate_MicroExpFuseNet.py)

Comment: @MrFuppes Please check the entire code 
https://github.com/bogireddytejareddy/micro-expression-recognition/blob/master/SMIC/MicroExpSTCNN.py 

The error is on line 89

Comment: Ok I see, and you use the same training data, i.e. at least 18 images for each positive/negative/suprise? Did you make sure these are all loaded and processed correctly?

Comment: @MrFuppes Also, I have added  `training_list = [a.reshape(-1, 2) for a in training_list]`  before `training_list = numpy.asarray(training_list)` on my own because it was throwing error `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (64,64,10) into shape (64,64)` 
[line74]

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes, I have the same dataset and have loaded them correctly

Comment: This is pretty much a guessing game ;-) But line 74 says `training_list = numpy.asarray(training_list)`, there's no broadcasting going on here, so I guess you got that error from somewhere else - also your `training_list` should be of shape (3, 64, 64, 18), not (64, 64, 10) (as defined in line 18, `image_rows, image_columns, image_depth = 64, 64, 18`).

Comment: @MrFuppes I don't know, the error window was pointing to line corresponding `training_list = numpy.asarray(training_list)` only. I googled it and added `training_list = [a.reshape(-1, 2) for a in training_list]` just before it . 

Now the error is on Too many indices part [line 89]

P.S : I have to show this as my major project tomorrow, I don't know how to thank you but please stay with me, you are a lifesaver for me right now.

Comment: Well, you definitely picked a challenge there. I would not consider this code especially user-friendly ;-) I hope you'll get it running!

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear, you gave more indices in the brackets than the array has dimensions.

Check the shapes of training_set and trainingframes -> print(training_set.shape())

Comment: Hey, the shape of training_set is printed as (7, 1, 64, 64, 18)
and the shape of trainingframes is printed as (7,)
Now please tell me what to change in the code ? 
Many thanx

Comment: I think you need to look up how arrays work, you are accessing indices in the trainingframes array that do not exist.

Comment: (1.1) - this should be a comment (1.2) - yes you need to wait until your rep unlocks that ability (2) - in principle, I'd say you're right (3) - from a bit further away, it looks like there's more than the indexing issue, considering all the (unnecesary) conversions between `list` and `numpy.ndarray` as well as the hard-coded numbers...